# How to access duplicate values in a JSON array and set each to a unique variable in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am running an ansible playbook which outputs my information in JSON. This array has a loop that has multiple identical keys with different values. Please see below, I am interested in the "intf_id":

```
"stdout": [
    {
        "TABLE_cdp_neighbor_brief_info": {
            "ROW_cdp_neighbor_brief_info": [
                {
                    "capability": [
                        "switch", 
                        "IGMP_cnd_filtering"
                    ], 
                    "device_id": "osw1J15", 
                    "ifindex": "83886080", 
                    "intf_id": "mgmt0", 
                    "platform_id": "cisco WS-C2960X-48TS-LL", 
                    "port_id": "GigabitEthernet0/45", 
                    "ttl": "160"
                }, 
                {
                    "capability": [
                        "router", 
                        "switch", 
                        "Supports-STP-Dispute"
                    ], 
                    "device_id": "spine01", 
                    "ifindex": "436232192", 
                    "intf_id": "Ethernet1/49", 
                    "platform_id": "N9K-C9508", 
                    "port_id": "Ethernet1/11", 
                    "ttl": "159"
                }, 
                {
                    "capability": [
                        "router", 
                        "switch", 
                        "Supports-STP-Dispute"
                    ], 
                    "device_id": "spine02", 
                    "ifindex": "436232704", 
                    "intf_id": "Ethernet1/50", 
                    "platform_id": "N9K-C9508", 
                    "port_id": "Ethernet1/11", 
                    "ttl": "127"
                }, 
                {
                    "capability": [
                        "router", 
                        "switch", 
                        "IGMP_cnd_filtering", 
                        "Supports-STP-Dispute"
                    ], 
                    "device_id": "leaf1J1402", 
                    "ifindex": "436234240", 
                    "intf_id": "Ethernet1/53", 
                    "platform_id": "N9K-C93180YC-EX", 
                    "port_id": "Ethernet1/53", 
                    "ttl": "175"
                }, 
                {
                    "capability": [
                        "router", 
                        "switch", 
                        "IGMP_cnd_filtering", 
                        "Supports-STP-Dispute"
                    ], 
                    "device_id": "leaf1J1402", 
                    "ifindex": "436234752", 
                    "intf_id": "Ethernet1/54", 
                    "platform_id": "N9K-C93180YC-EX", 
                    "port_id": "Ethernet1/54", 
                    "ttl": "175"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "neigh_count": "5"
    }
]
```

Currently I can access the first iteration of "intf_id" with :

```
- debug: msg="{{ list.stdout[0].TABLE_cdp_neighbor_brief_info.ROW_cdp_neighbor_brief_info[0].intf_id }}"
```

I feel like I'm close, but cannot figure out how to get each iteration of "intf_id". I can get subsequent ones by changing ROW_cdp_neighbor_brief_info[0] to [1] or [2], etc. I need to be able to access each key, without knowing how many keys there will be. Each value to the keys also need to be individually callable by subsequent tasks.

1) How do I get ansible to debug each iteration?

2) Depending on the answer to 1, how can I assign a particualr variable to each value? (ie. interface1, interface2, interface3...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter `json_query` with `jmespath` syntax to loop over the various elements `intf_id` this way

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: populate router data from json
      set_fact:
        data: "{{ lookup('file','so-router-info.json') }}"

    - name: looping over interfaces
      debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ data | json_query('TABLE_cdp_neighbor_brief_info.ROW_cdp_neighbor_brief_info[*].intf_id') }}"
```

it gives this output

```
…
TASK [looping over interfaces] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=mgmt0) => {
    "item": "mgmt0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Ethernet1/49) => {
    "item": "Ethernet1/49"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Ethernet1/50) => {
    "item": "Ethernet1/50"
…
```

You can use the site http://jmespath.org/ to tests filters

Comment: Really appreciate the direction here, it looks real promising. Unfortunately when I run those tasks I get this: "fatal: [leaf1J1401.clt2]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: . Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup.""

Any thoughts?

Comment: My answer and the one from Vladimir are the same (look at the query passed to `json_query`), I just put your data in a separate file, and change the variable name. Don't bother tweaking to make it works

Comment: I cannot upvote them as I am a new member, thank you though

Answer (score 1):

[ansible-playbook json_query.yml](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-examples/tree/master/examples/example-020)

```
tasks:                                                                                                                      
- name:                                                                                                                   
  debug:                                                                                                                  
    msg: "{{ item }}"                                                                                                     
  loop: "{{ stdout | json_query('TABLE_cdp_neighbor_brief_info.ROW_cdp_neighbor_brief_info[*].intf_id') }}"
```

(output abridged)

```
"msg": "mgmt0"
"msg": "Ethernet1/49"
"msg": "Ethernet1/50"
"msg": "Ethernet1/53"
"msg": "Ethernet1/54"
```

Comment: This worked! Though I did edit it slightly..

- debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ list.stdout[0] | json_query('TABLE_cdp_neighbor_brief_info.ROW_cdp_neighbor_brief_info[*].intf_id') }}"

Comment: Next task is to call each of those outputs as a distinct variable to be used later on in this playbook...I'll see where I can get with that, unless you have any more ideas? Thanks for the json_query idea, I will have to look more into that.